# Cannot resolve symbol 'textview' in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am brand new to Android Studio. I have been using a simple tutorial.
I got to a step and my code looks like the first picture that says:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'textview'`

I tried searching around, but could not find anything.

[This is the activity code with the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10N4m.png)
[The xml file that goes along with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN40m.png)

Answer (score 1):

you are using EditText in your xml remove space of ems write like this

```
android:ems=""
EditText edt = (EditText)(findViewByID(R.id.editText)
```

to get text

```
String value = edt.getText().toString();
```

create a Text view in your xml , and then cast textview in java

```
TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewByID(R.id.textview_id);
txt.setText(value);
```

Comment: How do I create a text view in my xml?

Comment: sorry for the late answer check this website https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

You have put id as "editText" and you are trying to find "textview". In R.id file there is no entry by name of textview, that's why it is throwing the error.
And also remove space between "android:" and "ems"

Answer (score 0):

You have created a *EditText* in the xml file and there is no TextView in it. You should fetch the EditText from it and set it's text. Like this :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setText(message);
```

Also remove the space between *android:* and *ems='10'*.